# Laravel controller thinks my function is undefined

Tags: php, laravel

Pretty simple.  I'm trying to call a function from within my controller.  The function is, in fact, defined.  Yet, when the function is called I get "PHP Fatal Error: Call to undefined function validate() ..."

Here's my code.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

```
<?php

class HomeController extends BaseController {

    /**
     * Controller for the index action of the home page.  Displays the landing page.
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return View::make('landing', array('success' => false));
    }

    /**
     * Controller to handle processing the contact form and re-displaying the landing page
     */
    public function processForm()
    {
        $form_array = array();
        $errors = array();

        foreach (array('email','fname','lname','message','newsletter') as $val)
        {
            if (isset($_POST[$val]))
                $form_array[$val] = $_POST[$val];
            else
                $form_array[$val] = null;
        }

        $form_ok = validate();

        if ($form_ok)
        {
            echo "GOOD!";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "BAD!";
        }
    }

    /**
     * Helper function for validating the form.  Returns true if the form was 
     * submitted without errors.
     */
    public function validate()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to call `$this->validate()`, instead of `validate()`.  You've defined `validate()` as a class method, not a stand alone function.

Answer (score 4):

You should try to refer to the actual controller.

Both of these will work.

```
 $form_ok = self::validate();
```

or

```
$this->validate();
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be $this->validate as its referring to a method within the class.